# Change line guide frequency in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some dart code I am looking at in vscode.

The dart code uses 4 space indentation (literal 4 space, opposed to tabs).

When I view the code in vscode, it is putting line guides every two spaces. This doesn't make any sense since the indentation only occurs every 4 spaces. So it is essentially showing line guides to no where.

Observe the following screenshot

[image]

How can I fix this???

Comment: You will want to update the setting for: editor.tabSize

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Files > preferences > settings > select:Editor-Tab size** You can change tab-size there.

**Note:** *If you are using Eslint or Prettier make sure your editor settings are not overriding*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that editor.tabsize setting is being overridden by language specific settings.

To fix I put the following in my user settings.json file...

```
"[dart]":  {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
},
```